# AppEngine Flexible with custom runtime - logging challenge

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, gae-module

Let's say my custom runtime uses a container with a bash process in it.

```
#snippet
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/zip-splitter
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/zip-splitter
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/zip-splitter

CMD ["/var/local/zip-splitter/entry.sh"]
```

In entry.sh I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "Starting cron in the background"
cron -f -L 0  &

#
# Respond to liveness & readiness checks from AppEngine
#
echo "Starting gunicorn"
cd /var/local/zip-splitter && gunicorn -b :8080 main:app
```

Now the trouble I am having lies with the jobs scheduled by cron.  How do I get stdout/stderr from said jobs to reach my GCP console logs ?

I have tried:

1. using the Linux "logger" command by piping stdout & stderr
2. directing stdout & stderr to "local files" in the container in
   /var/log
3. using "gcloud logs" (couldn't get nice log lines)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Docs seem to indicate that `stdout`/`stderr` should by default be captured as [Runtime logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#runtime_logs), so try not redirect them. Also [Custom logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#custom_logs) may be of interest (but I didn't see exactly how to configure them).

Comment: @DanCornilescu  Are you sure this covers also commands running through cron ?

Comment: Not really, saw nothing in the logs docs specifically about cron. But the GAE cron service is simply issuing `GET` requests to your app, don't you see the corresponding logs just as request logs? Or are you using cron differently? (kinda suspecting this from your question)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for trying to help. I just want to point out I am using a custom runtime.

Comment: Saw that. But if you're using standard GAE cron (i.e. via `cron.yaml`) it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Excellent point.  I could get rid of the container cron daemon and leverage GAE's cron for this particular service in my application. Thanks for this perspective, I had my nose stuck on the tree.